# What is this CronJobs means?

Tags: cron

I recently study a newsletter system, there is a Cronjobs like this, I really do not contact linux Cronjobs before, anyone can explain it for me? Thank you very much.

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.ynhwebdev.de/newsletter/mails/sendAll
```

Answer (score 2):

this command just downloads the web page "http://www.ynhwebdev.de/newsletter/mails/sendAll" which I assume is doing something on the server side (e.g. send some mails?) and sends the result to root (or whoever gets the cron mail)

If you list your cronjobs with

```
crontab -l
```

it should show 5 colums like

```
0 5 * * * wget....
```

which means it is executed at 05:00 every day.

Comment: Thanks. If I add this command to my linux server, when it will runs? It's not setting up the time.

Comment: if you list your cronjobs with

Comment: if you list your cronjobs with

    crontab -l

it should show 5 colums like 

    0 5 * * * wget....

which means it is executed at 05:00 every day.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually about programming.

Please read the [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) entry on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the Cron entry on wiki, but I still have no idea when the script will run according to that command. There is always have a time like "01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly". But there is not setting running time in my question cronjobs.